# Science Fiction Series about human scientists forced to live on high gravity planet by stronger aliens

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, hard-sci-fi, genetics

I'm trying to find the name of a series about a ship of scientists captured by aliens and forced to live on a planet with a gravity force greater than Earth's. The aliens are much stronger and faster than humans, and their fighting prowess is how positions are determined in the alien society.

The humans use their technology and knowledge of genetics to make life on the planet easier and eventually modify their children to be able to fight back against the aliens. If my memory is correct the captain was Asian and the genetically modified were referred to as T3s and T4s to denote what level of genetic mod they were. It was a book on oyser.com and was a series.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. I recommend a look at our [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) to story id questions in hopes that it might jog your memory for more details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SciFi book series about a collection of humans who get taken by a lightning quick alien race](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/198401/scifi-book-series-about-a-collection-of-humans-who-get-taken-by-a-lightning-quic)

Comment: @Paulie_D The answer here is not accepted and so this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Koban series by [Stephen W Bennett](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/b/stephen-w-bennett/)

1. [Koban (2012)](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/b/stephen-w-bennett/koban.htm)

The Krall have used thousands of years of combat to select the genes of the strongest and fastest warriors. They are a species determined to dominate the galaxy, through annihilation or enslavement of every opponent.

Koban is an uninhabited high gravity planet with impossibly fast savage animals, which employ organic superconducting nerves. This deadly world is where the Krall are testing humans for fighting capability. We are useful only if we can fight well. If not, they will destroy us swiftly, as they have other species. They have slaves, and we're poor tasting meat animals, so we fight or die. The Krall will use us, if worthy, seeking physical perfection through attrition of war, one planet at a time.

Growing weary of our failures in testing, the ruthless Krall are on the verge of a decision to eliminate our species. A ship carrying bio-scientists is captured for combat testing. The choice for Captain Mirikami and the scientists is simple: Prove we can produce better, smarter fighters quickly, or humanity is doomed to rapid extermination.

But the Krall are only half the problem. We must survive Koban's gravity and superfast animals. The tiger-like rippers with skin contact telepathy are predators too fast and powerful for the Krall to face. Our solution is genetic: If you can't beat them as you are, become human rippers.

The Krall will learn another species can bypass natural selection

2. The Mark of Koban (2013)
3. Rise of the Kobani (2013)
4. Shattered Worlds (2014)
5. A Federation Forged in Fire (2015)
6. Conflict and Empire (2016)
7. When Empires Collide (2017)